# how to create sub task in Visual Studio Team Services API

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to create a sub-task of a User Story, in Visual Studio Team Services, from my Mob App. How can I make it the right way? Whether I should use query or is there any direct endpoint for adding a subtask...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same so that added the user story to add a task. Then you add a link from the team to its parent.

https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items#addalink

The doc above does how to create a task with a link using the REST API.

Comment: Thanks MrHinsh I did the same way before ur reply, but it will help others... Thanks...